# Potential Source for data-request related questions

Tags: discussion

A lot of the [data-request](https://opendata.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/data-request) questions seems to be from researcher/academic dataset. [Academic Torrents](http://academictorrents.com/) is a platform to share research related datasets and papers through a peer-to-peer network.

I know this isn't a question or suggestion, but I think this is of interest for this community and could be a good point to search to answer [data-request](https://opendata.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/data-request) questions.

P.S. I am not related with this initiative.